# Can't find file Logfile

Tags: dr-memory

Dr-Memory won't debug my application, I tried allready the `-logdir` option (I use `-logdir C:\Users\r0b3\temp\drmemory`).

The Error Message is

```
WARNING: unable to locate results file since can't open
C:\Users\r0b3\temp\drmemory/resfile.7116: 2
~~Dr.M~~ WARNING: application exited with abnormal code 0xc0000005
```

Any hints?

Comment: it allows the user name with English letters only

Comment: @haifzhan so i created a folder in the users dir, and it doesn't work :/ (it creates folders there so it CAN write) WARNING: unable to locate results file since can't open C:\Users\mytempuser/resfile.10876: 2

Comment: hah i got it, i just installed dr-memory and didn't use the zip file...works